# System.Format exception in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

objDR["sidate"].ToString() has the date in this format "01-17-78" where objDR is a datarow.
When i am doing the following :

```
    Convert.ToDateTime(objDR["sidate"].ToString())
```

I am getting a System.Format exception.
What could possibly be causing this?

Edit:
The exception is not coming now.Refer Marked answer. Just one more question : the "MM-dd-yy" used in the middle is used for conversion of date from one format to other or it is used for some other purpose? Because i changed it to "M-d-yy" but the format did not change.

Comment: Use DateTime.ParseExact() with a format mask - your input string is not a format that's recognized by ToDateTime().

Comment: That code could be problematic if the database has a format different that the culture used in the client. If the database column is of type DateTime, you could avoid the conversion and just  direct cast it `(DateTime)objDR["sidate"]`. If it is not, the pasing should be done, check Pranav's answer on how to parse using a culture and format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to provide dateformat.

Try this 
`DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("01-17-78", "MM-dd-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: You could also suggest a direct cast of the DataColumn if it is the right type.

Comment: The exception is not coming now.
Just one more question : the "MM-dd-yy" used in the middle is used for conversion of date from one format to other or it is used for some other purpose?
Because i changed it to "M-d-yy" but the format did not change.

Comment: @VikeshGupta, it is not like that, here, your data format is "MM-dd-yy". if you changed to "yy-MM-dd" then you will get error. if you pass "78-01-07" then "yy-Mm-dd" will work.

Answer (score 1):

The `Convert.ToDateTime()` method takes in consideration your current culture in order to use that method you must make sure that the format of the DateTime you are passing to the method is the same format as your current culture.

Otherwise, you can do the following:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(objDR["sidate"].ToString(),CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Another solution is to use the `DateTime.ParseExact()` method:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(objDR["sidate"].ToString(), "MM-dd-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2) to `DateTime` struct in MSDN.
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_Parse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) to `DateTime.Parse(String, IFormatProvider)` method overload in MSDN.
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToDateTime_System_String_) to the `Convert.ToDateTime()` method in MSDN.
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) to the `DateTime.ParseExact()` method on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your current culture. Convert.ToDateTime uses the current culture to determine the convert format [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToDateTime_System_String_) the remakrs.

But one solution is to use

```
DateTime.Parse(objDR["sidate"].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

so the culture is programmer given.